# set value to devise form value with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have this makeid function which returns a random string of 10 characters

```
function makeid() {
       var text = "";
       var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

       for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
       return text;
}
```

I want to manually put this string to my devise form like this :

```
<div class="user_field">
        <div class="email">`enter code here`
          <%= f.label :email %><br />
      </div>
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" , value: <script>makeid();</script>%>
      </div>
```

Any thoughts??

Comment: Migrate the function to rails.

Comment: Sorry I am new to Ruby on rails. What do you mean by migrating a function?

Comment: By migrating, I meant to write this logic on Rails side, and use it from there. Whatever you write between `<%= ... %>` are rendered by Rails engine.

Comment: So I need to write my function between <%= ... %> ?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your makeid function as a ruby method, and put it into app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
def makeid
  (('A'..'Z').to_a + ('a'..'z').to_a + (0..9).to_a).sample(10).join()
end
```

Then you can call that helper in your templates:

```
<div class="user_field">
  <div class="email">`enter code here`
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
  </div>
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" , value: makeid() %>
</div>
```